# react-native flatlist with dynamic rows and columns

Tags: react-native, wrapper, react-native-flatlist, flatlist, react-native-listview

I'm trying to build a simple layout using FlatList in react-native application like this:
[example-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnfnM.jpg). I need to create a dynamic layout depending on the item's index, so if index ===0 1st image should be wide and the column below should be 2 smaller images in a row, this is my code.

With this logic I can display 1st image as wide but the rest images are not displayed correctly, I get something like this [current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd3Bv.png) The smaller image below the wide image  has an empty space next to it, if I change index === 5 same things happens, the column below the wide image has a spot where the other smaller image should be. I can't figure out why is this happening and how to fix it, I've read other posts here too. Any advise and help is greatly appreciated.

```
<FlatList
         showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
         contentContainerStyle={{
         alignSelf: 'center',
         alignItems: 'center',
         }}
         columnWrapperStyle={{flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
         data={layoutData}
         renderItem={({item, index}) =>
                    index === 0 ? (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.container}
                    <Image
                    style={styles.wideImg}
                    />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
              )  : (

                    <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.container}
                    <Image
                    style={styles.img}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )
            }
            numColumns={2}
          />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of you set `numColumns`={2}, this makes `FlatList` renders every two items into a row. First large item and second item are in the same row, third item and forth item are in the new row. So there will be a spot beside the second item. You can set `numColumns` to the length of `layoutData` instead of `2`.

```
    <FlatList
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     contentContainerStyle={{
     alignSelf: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     }}
     columnWrapperStyle={{flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
     data={layoutData}
     renderItem={({item, index}) =>
                index === 0 ? (
                <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.container, { width: '100%', height: 50, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1 }]}
                >
                {/* <Image
                style={styles.wideImg}
                /> */}
                </TouchableOpacity>
          )  : (

                <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.container, { width: '50%', height: 50, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1 }]}
                >
                {/* <Image
                style={styles.img}
                /> */}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        }
        numColumns={layoutData.length}
      />
```

Comment: thank you for you reply, but I get "Changing numColumns on the fly is not supported. Change the key prop on FlatList when changing the number of columns to force a fresh render of the component." error when I set  numColumns={layoutData.length}

Comment: You need to refresh the page after changed the  numColumns.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, I just added key ={layoutData.length} before numColumns otherwise app was crashing.

Comment: Great, can you please write that line here?